# Perl: unable to get the correct match from the file

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I need help with my script. I am writing a script that will check if the username is still existing in `/etc/passwd`. I know this can be done on BASH but as much as possible I want to avoid using it, and just focus on writing using Perl instead.

Okay, so my problem is that, my script could not find the right match in my `$password_file`. I still got the `No root found` error even though it is still in the file.

Execution of the script.

```
jpd@skriv ~ $ grep root /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
jpd@skriv ~ $ ~/Copy/documents/scripts/my_perl/test.pl root
Applying pattern match (m//) to @id will act on scalar(@id) at /home/jpd/Copy/documents/scripts/my_perl/test.pl line 16.
No root found!
jpd@skriv ~ $
```

Also, why do I always get this "Applying pattern match..." warning?

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $stdin = $ARGV[0];
my $password_file = '/etc/passwd';

open (PWD, $password_file) || die "Error: $!\n";
    my @lines = (<PWD>);
close PWD;

for my $line (@lines) {
    my @list = split /:/, $line;
    my @id = "$list[0]\n";
    if (@id =~ m/$stdin/) {
        die "Match found!\n";
    } else {
        print "No $stdin found!\n";
        exit 0;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Regards,
sedawkgrep
Perl Newbie

Comment: Array's are the wrong data structure to use in this case.  It would be much better to load the usernames (and the other fields if needed) into a hash.  Then it would be a simple hash lookup to see if the supplied username is a key in the hash.  Since this looks to be a class homework assignment, I will hold off providing the actual code.

Comment: the `perldoc -f getpwnam` can help greatly reduce the script. like `perl -E 'exit !defined getpwnam($ARGV[0])' root` will return exit status `0` for existing user, and for nonexisting user `rootxxx` will return `1` (bash convention).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a few things to point out regarding your code:

- Good job using [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html).  They should be included in EVERY perl script.
- Pick meaningful variable names.

  `$stdin` is too generic.  `$username` does a better job of documenting the intent of your script.
- Concerning your file processing:

  - Include [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html) anytime you're working with files.

    This pragma will automatically handle error messages, and will give you better information than just `"Error: $!\n"`.  Also, if you are wanting to do a manual error messages, be sure to remove the new line from your message or `die` won't report the line number.
  - Use Lexical file handles and the three argument form of `open`

    ```
    open my $fh, '<', $password_file;
    ```
  - Don't load an entire file into memory unless you need to.  Instead, use `while` loop and process the file line by line
- Concerning your comparison: `@id =~ m/$stdin/`:

  - Always use a scalar to the left of comparison `=~`

    The [comparison operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Relational-Operators) binds a scalar to a pattern.  Therefore the line `@id =~ m/$stdin/` is actually comparing the size of `@id` to your pattern: `"1" =~ m/$stdin/`.  This is obviously a bug.
  - Be sure to escape the regular expression special characters using [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) or `\Q...\E`:

    ```
    $list[0] =~ m/\Q$stdin/
    ```
  - Since you actually want a direct equality, don't use a regex at all, but instead use [`eq`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eq.html)
- You're exiting after only processing the first line of your file.

  In one fork you're dying if you find a match in the first line.  In your other fork, you're exiting with the assumption that no other lines are going to match either.

With these changes, I would correct your script to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $username = $ARGV[0];
my $password_file = '/etc/passwd';

open my $fh, '<', $password_file;

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my @cols = split /:/;
    if ($cols[0] eq $username) {
        die "Match found!\n";
    }
}

print "No $username found!\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $stdin = $ARGV[0];
my $password_file = '/etc/passwd';

open (PWD,"<$password_file");
my @lines = <PWD>;

my @varr = grep (m/root/, @lines);
```

Then check varr array and split it if you need.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using a hash for key lookups, but with minimal modification this should work:

```
open my $in, '<', 'in.txt';

my $stdin = $ARGV[0];

while(<$in>){
    chomp;
    my @list = split(/\:/);
    my ($id) = $list[0];
    if ($id eq $stdin) {
        die "Match found\n";
    }
}
```